# How to sort emp names list in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am listing employee details and want to sort by names, id, salary etc. However, I wasn't able to list and sort the items since I am beginner in Javascript.

Below is my attempt:

```
<div id="showtable"></div>
<br/>
<button onclick="showName()">Sort by Name</button>
<button onclick="">Sort by Age</button>
<button onclick="">Sort by Desending</button>
<button onclick="">Sort by Gender</button>
<button onclick="">Sort by Salary</button>
```

```
var myemp = [{
    name: "selva",
    age: 32,
    gender: "male",
    salary: 20000
  },
  {
    name: "raj",
    age: 32,
    gender: "male",
    salary: 20000
  },
  {
    name: "Priya",
    age: 28,
    gender: "female",
    salary: 20000
  }

];

function myEmployee() {
  var emplist = "<div>"
  for (var i = 0; i < myemp.length; i++) {
    emplist += "<ul>";
    emplist += "<li>" + myemp[i].name + "</li>";
    emplist += "<li>" + myemp[i].age + "</li>";
    emplist += "<li>" + myemp[i].gender + "</li>";
    emplist += "<li>" + myemp[i].salary + "</li>";
    emplist += "</ul>" + "<br>" + "<br>";
  }
  emplist += "</div>";
  document.getElementById("showtable").innerHTML = emplist;
}

function showName() {
  myemp.sort(function(myemp1, myemp2) {
    if (myemp1.name > myemp2.name) {
      return 1;
    } else(myemp1.name < myemp2.name) {
      return -1;
    }
    else return 0;
  });
  myEmployee();
}
```

Would you please help me out? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe there is a syntax error, which should appear in the browser console. Inside the sort, the first `else`, should likely be an `else if`, so that the last else will return 0 as expected.

Comment: (You can open the browser console using F12.)

Comment: `} else if (myemp1.name < myemp2.name){
                        return -1;`  add if after else

Comment: When you say _"sort by names, id, salary etc"_, do you mean: in that order? For example: if you have 2 _John Smith's_, you sort them by `id` next, then by `salary`, etc.